# How to import generics in angular / typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics, abstract-class

**TLDR**: How to import abstract classes and/or generics in angular properly?

---

I'm trying to create a generic Angular component and then inherit usual components from it. I successfully created a generic service and a generic component, however when I try to import any of these TS gives me an error.

```
// Other imports above

// This imports FINE:
import {DtoBase} from "src/app/modules/shared/dto-base";    
// This throws an ERROR:
// import {GenericService} from "src/app/modules/shared/generic.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css']
})
export class ItemsComponent {
    ...
```

generic.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GenericService<T extends DtoBase> {
    ...
```

When I try to uncomment the `import {GenericService}` it throws a huge error with totally weird error statements (I'll attach the complete error below). I assume that I should export this service somehow from my Shared module, but it doesn't allow me to do it as it's an abstract class which can not be instantiated. If I try to add an export for a GenericService or GenericComponent it gives this error:

```
Class GenericComponent is neither an Angular component nor directive nor pipe 
TS2322: Type 'typeof GenericComponent' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.   
Type 'typeof GenericComponent' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.
```

Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

generic.component.ts (it shouldn't be a component because it's a base abstract class, if I try to make it into a component it gives an error)

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class GenericComponent<T extends DtoBase, TService extends GenericService<T>>
  implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
```

The whole error message that I'm getting if I try to uncomment `import {GenericService}` in `items.component.ts` (this error makes 0 sense):

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/diagnostics/index.d.ts:10:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/diagnost
ics/src/error_code"' has no exported member 'COMPILER_ERRORS_WITH_GUIDES'.

10 export { COMPILER_ERRORS_WITH_GUIDES, ERROR_DETAILS_PAGE_BASE_URL, ErrorCode, ngErrorCode } from './src/error_code';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/diagnostics/index.d.ts:10:39 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/diagnost
ics/src/error_code"' has no exported member 'ERROR_DETAILS_PAGE_BASE_URL'.

10 export { COMPILER_ERRORS_WITH_GUIDES, ERROR_DETAILS_PAGE_BASE_URL, ErrorCode, ngErrorCode } from './src/error_code';
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/diagnostics/index.d.ts:10:79 - error TS2724: '"@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/diagnostics/src
/error_code"' has no exported member named 'ngErrorCode'. Did you mean 'ErrorCode'?

10 export { COMPILER_ERRORS_WITH_GUIDES, ERROR_DETAILS_PAGE_BASE_URL, ErrorCode, ngErrorCode } from './src/error_code';
                                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/diagnostics/src/error_code.d.ts:12:21
    12 export declare enum ErrorCode {
                           ~~~~~~~~~
    'ErrorCode' is declared here.


Error: node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.d.ts:9:23 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'path'.
'D:/Work/repos/viddy.ui/node_modules/path/path.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/path` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'path';`

9 import * as path from 'path';
                        ~~~~~~
```

Thank you everyone who tries to help in advance.

Comment: Try removing providedIn:root?

Comment: First of all your ```GenericComponent``` should not be an ```Injectable```. It should be just a normal abstract class.